# Resume upload with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, file-upload, image-upload

Is it possible to resume an upload with SharePoint Online? I've been looking at the following at doesn't appear to be supported.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileStartUpload

First the file has to exist, and even if a file does exist it returns NotImplementedException

Has any one had any experience of resuming an upload whether it be a file stream or a response stream?

I've also tried AddRange header on webrequests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported at this time. It is on the road map. Look at "SharePoint API partial file upload support" here http://roadmap.office.com/en-us